# イラストレーターの図形を扱うように、Swiftで、図形として線を扱う方法はないでしょうか？

Tags: swift

イラストレーターの図形を扱うように、
図形として線を扱う方法はないでしょうか？

ある点からある点まで線を引いて、
その線自体をドラッグして移動したり、回転したり、縮小したりといった操作を想定しています。

Answer (score 1):

**Core Graphics**というフレームワークを使います。**Quartz2D**とも呼ばれているので、ネット検索するときは、両方をキーワードにするといいでしょう。

[Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH11-SW1)

グラフィック処理というのは、一朝一夕には習得できないほど大きなジャンルなので、コツコツ学習なさることをお勧めします。